# Bulk insert data into rails DB with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bulkinsert

I wanted to copy and bulk insert data to database (using [bulk_insert](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert) GEM), so I tried the following:

```
@questionnaires = Questionnaire.where(:id => params[:id])
@new_sections = []

@questionnaires.includes(:sections, :questions).each do |questionnaire|
  questionnaire.sections.each do |section|
    s = section.dup
    s.questionnaire_id = nil
    new_section = Section.new( s.attributes.reject{|k, v| ["id", "created_at", "updated_at"].include?(k)} )
    questions = []

    section.questions.each do |question|
      q = question.dup
      q.section_id = nil
      questions << q.attributes.reject{|k, v| ["id", "created_at", "updated_at"].include?(k)}
    end

    new_section.questions.build(questions)
    @new_sections << new_section
  end
end
```

Now, here `@new_sections` has all the sections with associated questions, but is not saved.

**SAVING**

```
Section.transaction do
  Section.bulk_insert values: @new_sections.map(&:attributes)
end
```

But, this only saves the sections but not it's associations. How can I save associations(questions) as well.

**EDIT**

Now, I came across this https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki GEM and I'm trying the Multi-Level Example, still questions are not saved. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I beleive you need to enable ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes (see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html for reference).

Afterwards you would need to change

```
section.questions
```

into

```
section.questions_attributes
```

and add

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
```

in Section model

Keep in mind i am not entirely sure how would it work with inserting existing questions as association.

Comment: @Abhi have you already resolved the issue? Or do you have NestedAttributes enabled? If the latter have you taken a look at the array name `questions_attributes` instead of `questions`? If the former, please close the question/accept the answer/post your own solution?